# wp_query not searching with apostrophe

Tags: wp-query, ajax, meta-query, escaping, htmlspecialchars-decode

I'm trying to search WP_Query for the data containing the phrase "Dalton's Law" in `meta_query`. This is an `AJAX` search, and here's what I"m doing:

```
//in this case $_POST['query'] is the phrase "Dalton's Law"

$query = apply_filters( 'get_search_query', $_POST['query'] );
$query = esc_html( $query );

$guide_meta_args   = array(
    'post_type'           => array( 'guide' ),
    'post_status'         => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    'posts_per_page'      => 4,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'guide_raw_data',
            'value'   => $query,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    )

);
```

I will have success for typing up to "Dalton", but as soon as I get to the apostrophe, the search fails. When I get code back from the my javascript, i can `console.log` the search string and it is `dalton\&#039;s` So it appears that the encoding is working properly, but `WP_Query` doesn't like the apostrophe... does anyone have suggestions? Thanks so much!

Comment: Keep in mind that querying via post meta is very expensive, you'll also want to be sure it's saved HTML encoded too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [sanitize_text_field](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/) instead of `esc_html`

```
wp> $search_query = "Dalton's Law <br/>";
string(18) "Dalton's Law <br/>"
wp> $query = apply_filters( 'get_search_query', $search_query );
string(18) "Dalton's Law <br/>"
wp> $esc_html = esc_html( $query );
string(29) "Dalton&#039;s Law &lt;br/&gt;"
wp> $sanitized = sanitize_text_field( $query );
string(12) "Dalton's Law"
```

`esc_html` should be used to escape output before it goes *into* HTML.